# Selenium - The label is clicked (it changes colour for a moment) then the label reverts to the unclicked state

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN3OJ.png)

When I click on a button using XPath or CSS methods the button is highlighted for a moment. Then it changes back to the default colour as if the option is not chosen. When the automation is finished I get a user error that the button option was not selected.

I'm writing Java code with the latest Chrome driver. I've also tried Firefoxdriver. I've tried explicit wait and `Thread.sleep` and nothing worked.
This is the code - [Insurance Cover Type Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXOJ6.png)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'content\']/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[14]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/label")).click();
```

Similar labels on the screen can be clicked and selected. I searched questions and answers on this topic but i can't find a solution. I've added code and front end screen shots.

Comment: It looks like for some reason, the code listening to the click in the page crashed or was not registered. Though it's hard to say why exactly without a reproducible example.  It could be due to previous actions. Try step by step in debug mode and check the console of the browser for any error.

Comment: Note that a better locator would be either `by.cssSelector("[for='itemInsured.coverSelected1']")` or `by.xpath(".//*[not(child::*)][normalize-space()='Comprehensive']")` if by text.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your locator is incorrect (some indexes are off), at least when I checked it in Chrome using `$x()`.

While you *can* click the `LABEL`, I would suggest that you avoid the long XPath and instead use the ID for the contained `INPUT` and then reference the `LABEL` sibling. I tried it and it worked fine for me.

```
By.CssSelector("#itemInsured\\.coverSelected1 + label")
```

Comment: What do you mean by slightly off? Note that the label covers the input which means that the `<input>` is not visible/interactable.

Comment: @FlorentB. When I navigate to the site and Copy > Copy XPath from Chrome (as I'm assuming OP did), I get `//*[@id="content"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[14]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/label` which is slightly different than the locator that OP posted... so, "slightly off".

Comment: @FlorentB. You were right about the `INPUT` being hidden. I was executing in the dev console to confirm. I've updated my answer with code that works with Selenium. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffC Your answer still doesn't explains what you mean by _locator is slightly off_. Though you claimed _updated my answer with code that works with Selenium_ but there is a _bug_ in your _CssSelector_ and it won't work as you have escaped the `.` with `(\\)`. You need to change the _CssSelector_ to `By.CssSelector("#itemInsured\.coverSelected1 + label")` to get it work.

Comment: @DebanjanB I explained in my comment above to Florent what I meant by "slightly off." That doesn't really matter though, does it? No, the way I have the locator is properly escaped. I ran it and it works. Test it yourself. You should have done so before downvoting me... but you're doing it as revenge, not because it deserves it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be clicking on a label, and not on a button. Even if the label is inside a button, the event may be captured while it bubbles and cancelled. I'd try selecting exactly the object you want to handle the event.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the screenshot [Insurance Cover Type Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXOJ6.png), it seems that the `button` element that you want to interact with, is inside the `<lable>` tag. So when you are clicking on the button, it is basically clicking on `<label>` not the `<button>`. Can you please provide a screenshot of the dom by expanding the  tag.

Your locator should be like

```
By.xpath("//*[@id=\'content\']/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[14]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/label/button");
```

You just need to include the element in your `xpath` that is referring to the button element inside the `label`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code attempt you are trying to invoke `click()` method on the `<label>` tag which won't be accepting any click.

If you look into the *HTML* the `<label>` node have 2 child nodes, an `<input>` and another `<label>` node. You can invoke `click()` on the child `<label>` tag as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\ChromeDriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://services.aviva.ie/direct/product/car.htm?_flowId=motor-flow&_flowExecutionKey=e1s1')
element =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='radio coverType' and @name='itemInsured.coverSelected' and @value='0101']")
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='itemInsured.coverSelected1']"))).click()
```

Browser Snapshot :

[image: Comprehensive]

Answer (score 0):

Work with this code (this xpath: `//label[contains(text(), 'Comprehensive')]`):

```
public class Sof {

    /**
     * Specific logger
     */
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sof.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final OperatingSystem currentOperatingSystem = OperatingSystem.getCurrentOperatingSystem();
        String pathWebdriver = String.format("src/test/resources/drivers/%s/googlechrome/%s/chromedriver%s", currentOperatingSystem.getOperatingSystemDir(),
                SystemArchitecture.getCurrentSystemArchitecture().getSystemArchitectureName(), currentOperatingSystem.getSuffixBinary());

        if (!new File(pathWebdriver).setExecutable(true)) {
            logger.error("ERROR when change setExecutable on " + pathWebdriver);
        }

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathWebdriver);
        final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        driver.get("https://services.aviva.ie/direct/product/car.htm?_flowId=motor-flow&_flowExecutionKey=e1s1");
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Comprehensive')]"));
        element.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

[image]

*Note:* 
**If you do Web Interface tests with Java + Selenium, I advise you to use the [NoraUi](https://noraui.github.io/) Open Source Framework**